# Can you import bacpac file into Azure SQL Hyperscale?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I haven't found a way to import a bacpac file into Azure SQL Hyperscale and the tooling does not appear to support it.

I have tried all the normal tools(MGMT Studio/ SqlPackage) and the Azure Portal Import attempting to import a bacpac file into Azure SQL Hyperscale and none of them appear to support the 'Hyperscale' edition.

SqlPackage dumps out the error:

*** Argument 'Edition' has an invalid value: 'Hyperscale'.

The Azure Portal has Hyperscale option disabled and MGMT Studio does not list Hyperscale as an option.

I cannot find any documentation about this explicitly being unsupported for the 'Edition' of the DB. Matter of fact this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale-faq specifically states that "You can use all existing migration technologies to migrate to Hyperscale, including BACPAC, transactional replication, logical data loading".

How can you get an existing database into the Hyperscale environment?  Seems like the end around option may be to import into a different one and try to switch it to Hyperscale.

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is helpful/useful and was my original assumption and has been marked useful accordingly.  The actual answer at the moment appears to be NO but a workaround exists.

Answer (score 1):

[Azure SQL Hyperscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale#hyperscale-pricing-model) in Azure SQL Database is the newest service tier in the vCore-based purchasing model. This service tier is a highly scalable storage and compute performance tier that leverages the Azure architecture to scale out the storage and compute resources for an Azure SQL Database substantially beyond the limits available for the General Purpose and Business Critical service tiers.

I tried using SSMS to import a .bacpac file to my Azure sql server, there is no Hyperscale.

[image]

It's new and We could not import the bacpac file into Azure SQL Hyperscale tier directly for now. We can first import the file with other price tier.

For example, I import the file with Standard successfully.

[image]

Then I need do migrate the price tier to Hyperscale on Portal manually.
[image]

Hope this helps.